# How to create controllers in different namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Product model in my rails app. How can I create controllers and views in different namespace (for example 'api' namespace) through scaffold?

Comment: With `scaffold` it also created a model which would conflict with the existing `product.rb` model

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rails g scaffold api::session
```

Comment: This is giving the following error **uninitialized constant Api::Product**

Comment: I guess you didn't wrap you product model with module Api. And if model are used with module, you should either add table prefix 'api_' to your product model or add table_name = 'products' in your model, FYI

Answer (score 0):

To namespace controllers just create a new dir with desired controllers.
In your case location would be:

```
app/controllers/api/product_controller.rb
```

And controller would look like:

```
class Api::ProductController < ApplicationController
 ...
end
```

And corresponding route:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :products
 end
```

Comment: Would you not also need a `module Api` inside controllers dir for this to work?

Comment: No, because you're using it only for namespacing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The below should do

```
rails g scaffold Api/product
```

Comment: I already have a product model I dont want to create this model again

Comment: @LovishChoudhary That is what I said before. You need to delete the existing model if you want to use scaffold.

Comment: I can use scaffold_controller to create the just the controllers and views, it is generating the views and controller but when i try to create a new product i get this error **uninitialized constant Api::Product**

Comment: @LovishChoudhary Try to ask another question explaining what is the problem.

Comment: i tried changing Api::Product tp Product in my controller index, new and create action, then it is giving me this error **undefined method `products_path'**

Comment: @LovishChoudhary Please ask another question explaining your problem.

Comment: asked a different question **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320345/how-to-create-controllers-in-different-namespace-for-an-existing-model**