# How to create controllers in different namespace for an existing model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Product model in my rails app. Now I want to create a controller and views for this product model through scaffolding in a different namespace(api).

Till now I have tried using

```
rails g scaffold_controller product name:string price:integer
```

and after this I added the this to my routes file

```
namespace :api do
  resources :products
end
```

Now when I go to the link api/products . I get this error

```
uninitialized constant Api::Product
```

on the index action

```
def index
   @api_products = Api::Product.all
end
```

After this I removed the Api:: from my controller index, new and create action. After doing this my index url (/api/products) was working fine but now when I try to create a new product(/api/products/new) I get the following error

```
undefined method `products_path'
```

This is the code for my model file (location is models/)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Can anyone please help in implementing this correctly?

Comment: To which line line of code the error `uninitialized constant Api::Product` is pointing to? Please add it in the question.

Comment: Can you also add your model code to the question?

Comment: added the code for model

Answer (score 1):

You should move `product.rb` to `app/models/api` and change the ***class name*** to `Api::Product`

```
#app/models/api/product.rb
class Api::Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "products"
end
```

Comment: Now it is giving this error **SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: api_products: SELECT "api_products".* FROM "api_products"**

on this line **<% @api_products.each do |api_product| %>** of my index file

Comment: this worked, but is it possible to do it without changing the model file, because I have code from before and I  don't want to change that file ?

Comment: @LovishChoudhary No. Not possible. If you want to use namespaced controllers and views, then the model should be namespaced too.